# jQuery ajax, encapsulamento assíncrono

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-pattern

Eu gosto de *encapsulamento* pois reduz muito o código fonte, tenho feito o seguinte a respeito do ajax:

```
custom.ajax=function(obj,funcao,view){                                                  // FUNÇÃO AJAX
    var data = {'obj':obj,'funcao':funcao};                                             // SETA OS PARAMETROS
    var retorno;                                                                        // VAR DE RETORNO
    $.ajax({type:"POST", url:view, dataType:"json", data:data,async:false,              // FAZ UM AJAX SINCRONIZADO COM A FUNCAO
        success: function(json) { retorno = json; },                                    // RETORNO DO AJAX NO SUCCESS
        error: function(json) { retorno=json; },                                        // RETORNO DO AJAX NO ERROR
        beforeSend: function() { $('body').css('cursor','wait'); },                     // RETORNO DO AJAX NO ERROR
        complete: function(){ $('body').css('cursor','default'); }
    });                                                                                 // FIM DO AJAX        
    return retorno;                                                                     // RETORNO DA FUNÇÃO
};
```

Com esse código toda vez que quero fazer um ajax eu utilizo apenas 1 linha de código passando meus paramentros assim:

```
var r = custom.ajax(new Object(),'getConhecimentos','../view/cobranca/vRelacaoCobranca.php');
preencherTela(r); // para preencher o HTML.
```

O problema dessa técnica é que a minha pagina fica aguardando o ajax completar, ou seja a parte do assíncrono no caso parametro *async:true* seria a solução, o problema é que eu teria que escrever o ajax inteiro toda vez, não teria uma forma de encapsular? pois o restante da programação ficaria dentro do parametro *success* desta maneira:

```
var funcao = 'getConhecimentos';
var obj = new Object();  
var data = {'obj':obj,'funcao':funcao};                                             // SETA OS PARAMETROS
var view = '../view/cobranca/vRelacaoCobranca.php';

$.ajax({type:"POST", url:view, dataType:"json", data:data,async:true,              // FAZ UM AJAX SINCRONIZADO COM A FUNCAO
    success: function(json) { relCob.tableStyle(json,'jqxGrid-conhec'); },                                    // RETORNO DO AJAX NO SUCCESS
    error: function(json) { console.log(json) },                                        // RETORNO DO AJAX NO ERROR
    beforeSend: function() { $('body').css('cursor','wait'); },                     // RETORNO DO AJAX NO ERROR
    complete: function(){ $('body').css('cursor','default'); }
});
```

Minha pergunta é: teria algum modo de encapsular o ajax e manter ele de forma assíncrona? (*async:true*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maneira clássica de se resolver isso é passar um callback, ou usar a própria promessa retornada pelo Ajax. Vou mostrar exemplos.

#### Passando um callback

```
custom.ajax=function(obj,funcao,view, callback){                                                  // FUNÇÃO AJAX
    var data = {'obj':obj,'funcao':funcao};                                             // SETA OS PARAMETROS
    var retorno;                                                                        // VAR DE RETORNO
    $.ajax({type:"POST", url:view, dataType:"json", data:data,
        success: callback,                                    // RETORNO DO AJAX NO SUCCESS
        error: function(json) { retorno=json; },                                        // RETORNO DO AJAX NO ERROR
        beforeSend: function() { $('body').css('cursor','wait'); },                     // RETORNO DO AJAX NO ERROR
        complete: function(){ $('body').css('cursor','default'); }
    });                                                                                 // FIM DO AJAX        
}; 

var processa = function(json) {
    // faz algo com o json
}
custom.ajax({},'getConhecimentos','../view/cobranca/vRelacaoCobranca.php', processa);
```

#### Usando promises

```
custom.ajax=function(obj,funcao,view){                                                  // FUNÇÃO AJAX
    var data = {'obj':obj,'funcao':funcao};                                             // SETA OS PARAMETROS
    var retorno;                                                                        // VAR DE RETORNO
    return $.ajax({type:"POST", url:view, dataType:"json", data:data,
        beforeSend: function() { $('body').css('cursor','wait'); },                     
    });                                                                                              
}; 

var processa = function(json) {
    // faz algo com o json
}
var promessa = custom.ajax({},'getConhecimentos','../view/cobranca/vRelacaoCobranca.php');
promessa.done(processa);
```

Comment: resolveu com a promessa, não sei porque com o callback não funcionou, acho até que já tinha tentado uma vez com o callback e não tinha conseguido, mas a promessa já me resolve aqui obrigado!